# ItemContainerStyle reuse silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have control template with a checkbox as this:

```
 <Style x:Key="GeneralChkbxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">   
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <CheckBox ClickMode="Press" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter
    </Style>
```

I use this in a combobox and a listbox mentioning like this ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GeneralChkbxItemStyle .It works perfect when the datasource has a property named  Name .

But I am wondering how can I use this template with other data source having class which does not have a name property . It might have a property name2, or name 3 etc depending on the datasource.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Make a generic SelectionItemViewModel with 3 properties (Name, IsSelected and SourceObject) and use that one instead. SourceObject would contain the wrapped object. Another option is to create an Interface with the Name and IsSelected property that will have to be implemented by all types that can appear inside the combobox/listbox.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem in my case is, I am using WCF RIA services with EF . So I use the Model class generated by EF .

Answer (score 1):

In your template:

```
 <CheckBox ClickMode="Press"
           Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
           ContentTemplate="{templateBinding ContentTemplate}"
           IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then in your view:

```
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"..../>
<!--OR-->
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name2"..../>
<!--OR-->
......
```

Comment: The only issue now I have is when I have listbox inside a style <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GeneralChkbxItemStyle}"> This is not working. It shows the listbox but instead of Name , it shows Datasource.Item . Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You may use implicit data templates.

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="MyApp:Person">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="MyApp:Booking">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="GeneralChkbxItemStyle"
           TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <CheckBox ClickMode="Press"
                                  Content="{Binding .}"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```